# GAM structure when many random effect levels

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have a larg-ish dataset , ~ 57,000 observations. The dataset is an organisation-level dataset that describes organisational metrics through time. There is a single outcome of interest, `cat.norm.cit.impact`, which can only be a positive numeric value (or 0), and four main predictor variables:

1. `org.name`: the name of the individual organisation; factor variable with ~2,500 unique levels
2. `org.type`: classification of the organisations' type; factor variable with 4 unique levels
3. `region`: the geographic region where the organisation is located; factor variable with 8 unique levels
4. `year`: year when `cat.norm.cit.impact` was measured; numeric variable

The primary interest of the analysis is to investigate how `cat.norm.cit.impact` changes through time by `org.type`. However, I also expect that `cat.norm.cit.impact` will change through time according to `region`. The complicating factor is the random effect structure; `org.name` has ~2,500 unique levels and so fitting random intercepts, `s(org.name, bs = 're')`, and slopes, `s(org.name, year, bs = 're')`, is computationally [very demanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75349913/computation-time-gam/75352185#75352185). In an attempt to [reduce computation costs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/575538/estimating-separate-smooths-for-a-factor-with-hundreds-of-levels-using-gams) (see Q3 in answer), and remove the need for fitting separate random intercepts and slopes, I tried fitting a random smooth for each level of `org.name`, `s(org.name, year, bs = 'fs')`, but I run into memory errors.

I have now settled on the below model

```
ctrl <- gam.control(trace = T)
bam((cat.norm.cit.impact + 0.001) ~  
              org.type + # Parametric term for org.type, included due to use in by factor smooth
              region + # Parametric term for region, included due to use in a by factor smooth
              s(year) + # Global smooth of time/year
              s(year, by = org.type) + # Separate smooths of year for each level of org.type
              s(year, by = region) + # Separate smooths of year for each level of region
              s(org.name, bs = 're'), # Random intercept for each level of org.name
            data = dat, 
            method = "fREML", 
            family = Gamma(link = "log"), # Gamma distribution as outcome is positive only 
            select = T, 
            discrete = T, # To reduce computation time
            control = ctrl)
```

**Question:** Would such a model structure be an appropriate compromise given the key question of interest (effect of `org.type` through time/`year`) and given the many levels of random effects? I appreciate that accounting for clustering and the hierarchy in the dataset is important and necessary, but it is partly a side issue to the key question of interest, hence settling for the inclusion of only a random intercept for each level of `org.name` and no random slope.

While this model seemed reasonable in my head, its fit was average. All the smooths seem ok based on `gam.check()`, i.e. no p-value<0.05 and K-index all approximately 1, but the qq-plot is average (below). Deviance explained by the model was 35.4%.

I appreciate that `bam()` and `gam()` have largely been designed to fit smooths and not necessarily to fit complex random effect structures.

[image]

**Update:** The primary interest here is fitting non-linear responses, hence the original choice to use a GAM. However, given that the GAM appeared to be struggling with the many levels of the random effects I decided to try fitting an approximately similar model using `glmer()` in `lme4` which supposedly better handles random effects. Even with relatively basic and non-complex natural splines (df = 3) I encounter issues with model complexity when including random intercepts and slopes. A model with only random intercepts and slopes, and no other predictors, also encounters a similar problem.

```
glmer((cat.norm.cit.impact + 0.001) ~
+         org.type + 
+         region + 
+         ns(year, 3):org.type +
+         ns(year, 3):region + 
+           (1 | org.name) + 
+           (0 + year | org.name),
+       data = dat,
+       family = Gamma(link = "log"), nAGQ = 0)
```

Comment: If you want a gamma model, why not fit this with `gamm4::gamm4()`? - that will handle the random intercepts just fine (I mean it's not going to be quick to estimate such a model, but you won't hit memory issues in the same way you are with `gam()` or `bam()`. Using `gamm4` isn't a general solution because it can't handle all the families that `gam()` can, but for the standard exponential family ones `gamm4` is a good start.

Comment: Why do you keep including random slopes (linear) terms for `year` when you think all the other temporal effects are smooth but non-linear?

Comment: Don't add a small constant to responses (you'd be better off just adding 1 than such a small value as that small value will put your original 0s well away from the 1s and 2s: run this to see why: `log(c(0.001, 1, 2))`.

Comment: You don't say why the response is continuous but can include 0; often 0 isn't actually observable, so do you have real 0s or are the 0s observations that fall below some lower limit of detection? If they are real zeroes then consider the `tw()` family (but then you are back to `bam()`), but if they aren't real, you'll need to consider models for censored data or hurdle gamma models (but not in mgcv)

Comment: I don't mean this to be flippant, but you could solve your problems by throwing a bit of $ at them; either in the form of hardware with more RAM or renting time on a cloud-based instance with sufficient cores and RAM to fit the model you want to all your data. You can prototype the model with a random sample of levels of `org.name` so you can fit the model on your own machine, and spend the time you are now using to explore other packages on buying/setting up an instance to fit to the full data.

Comment: That said, also see package {bamlss}, which now has capability to fit large models (and can load data off disk while fitting, thus helping to avoid some memory bottlenecks - though note that I don't know if this will work for random effect terms). The background is in Umlauf, N., Seiler, J., Wetscher, M., Simon, T., Lang, S., Klein, N., 2023. Scalable Estimation for Structured Additive Distributional Regression. arXiv [stat.CO]. http://arxiv.org/abs/2301.05593

Comment: The above comments got long enough to be an *answer* but they're not really an answer as your question isn't focused enough. Perhaps you could consider my comments and edit your question (not just by adding more updates) to make it more focused.